# How do I use the outcome of my actionPerformed method to effect the main method - java

Tags: java, class, actionlistener, program-entry-point

I have a class called Screen containing the actionPerformed method.
I want a different outcome for the different menu items: random, aggressive and human.

This outcome effects the main method, however I am unsure how to link the two...

```
public class Screen extends JFrame
                implements ActionListener {

ActionListener listener;

JMenuItem random = new JMenuItem("Random");
JMenuItem aggressive = new JMenuItem("Aggressive");
JMenuItem human = new JMenuItem("Human");

public Screen(Board board){

  //menuBar items
  menu.add(random);
    random.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(aggressive);
    aggressive.addActionListener(this);
    menu.add(human);
    human.addActionListener(this);

  ....
  //sets up board of buttons and adds actionListener to each.
  ....
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if(e.getSource() == random){

      }
      if(e.getSource() == aggressive){

      }
      if(e.getSource() == human){

      }
    //code for the board buttons - nothing to do with the menu. 
    //But thought it might help
    if (numClicks == 0){
        JButton piece = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String xy = piece.getName();
        String x = xy.substring(0,1);
        String y = xy.substring(2,3);
        FromXInt = Integer.parseInt(x);
        FromYInt = Integer.parseInt(y); 
        System.out.println("From" + " " +FromXInt + "," + FromYInt);
    }
    else{
        JButton piece = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String xy = piece.getName();
        String x = xy.substring(0,1);
        String y = xy.substring(2,3);
        ToXInt = Integer.parseInt(x);
        ToYInt = Integer.parseInt(y);   
        System.out.println("To" + " " + ToXInt + "," + ToYInt);
    }
    numClicks++;
    if (numClicks >= 2){
        numClicks = 0;      
    }
    return;
}
}
```

My class which contains the main method:

```
public class Chess{

  public static void main(String [ ] args){

    Screen s = new Screen(board);

    // my attempt but doesn't work
    if (s.actionPerformed(e) == random){


    .....
```

note: I am new to Java and still trying to get my head round the linking of multiple classes.
--------------------The ActionPerformed method also contains events if buttons are clicked but I haven't added that code in because it over complicates things.--

Comment: You are not returning anything from actionPerformed so you can not compare it to anything in your main method. If you would add return e.getSource() in your actionPerformed method you could do that. I don't fully understand the functionality of your program though.

Comment: Did you add ActionListener to any onject?

Comment: Did you check what e.getSource() returns?

Comment: Can you add all the code? Why do you want to affect the main method? Don't you want to affect the screen? What are the empty if statements for?

Comment: The screen is the same regardless of which item is chosen. Basically the item chosen effects the way in which the chess pieces move. So I thought this meant the main method would be effected?

Comment: The empty statements are me trying to figure out how I would do it...

Comment: @hheather You can also pass Chess as an argument to Screen's constructor, then you could call its methods from Screen

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve @hheather?

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a public enum and sets the style variable according to the users menu choice:

```
package chess;
//...
public class Screen extends JFrame
        implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuItem random = new JMenuItem("Random");
    private JMenuItem aggressive = new JMenuItem("Aggressive");
    private JMenuItem human = new JMenuItem("Human");

    public enum PlayStyle {Random, Aggressive, Human};
    private PlayStyle style;

    public Screen(Board board) {

        //menuBar items
        menu.add(random);
        random.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(aggressive);
        aggressive.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(human);
        human.addActionListener(this);
        //....
        //sets up board of buttons and adds actionListener to each.  
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == random) {
            style=PlayStyle.Random;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == aggressive) {
            style=PlayStyle.Aggressive;
        }
        if (e.getSource() == human) {
            style=PlayStyle.Human;
        }

        //code for the board buttons - nothing to do with the menu. 
        //....
    }
    public PlayStyle getStyle(){
        return style;
    }

}
```

This is the class that contains the main method:

```
package chess;

import chess.Screen.PlayStyle;

public class Chess{

     public static void main(String [ ] args){
         Screen s = new Screen(board);

         // this attempt will work
         if (s.getStyle()==PlayStyle.Random) {
             ...
         } else if (s.getStyle()==PlayStyle.Aggressive){
             ...
```

Answer (score -3):

You are calling a method and it seems that you want to use something that comes back from that method but the method itself returns nothing, i.e. "void". I changed your Screen class so that the method returns something now.

```
public class Screen extends JFrame
                    implements ActionListener {
  public Source actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    ....

    if(e.getSource() == random){

    }
    if(e.getSource() == aggressive){

    }
    if(e.getSource() == human){

    }

    return e.getSource()
}
```

The main method will now be able to receive a result from the call and use it.

Comment: I get the error: The return type is incompatible with ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Comment: @Juru it is wrong, overriden method signature must be the same

Comment: @Suspended I don't know that it is an overridden message, missing the [at]Override annotation then.

Comment: @Juru ActionListener interface has the required signature, also, annotations are just optional, not requirements.

Comment: I know but I can't smell that with a snippet unless it has that annotation. The only reason its not a requirement is for backwards compatibility anyway, it should be required. I'm not required to know that actionPerformed comes from ActionListener,

Comment: @Juro If you want this to be quality answer and undo my downvote, you do have to know what comes from ActionListener. Now it has nothing to do with the problem on hand.

Comment: @zubergo If you want to be picky about my answer then let me return you the favor. Nowhere in the code it says that ActionListener is java.awt.event.ActionListener. Which would mean you can not conclude that actionPerformed is inherited from there. Maybe it is some interface that the op made. ;-)

Comment: Wrong no matter how you look at it.